# Get the exit code of processes forked from the master process

Tags: process, background-process, job-control

I have a master process (`run-jobs` below) that starts other jobs as its sub-processes. When the master process fails (e.g. database failure), it exits with a non-0 status code, which is good, and can be verified by looking into `$?` variable (`echo $?`).

However, I'd also like to inspect the exit codes of the sub-processes in case the master job fails. Is there a convenient way to check the exit code of `process_1` and `process_2` below, once the master process is gone?

This is simplified output of `ps auxf`:

`vagrant   5167  |           \_ php app/console run-jobs
vagrant   5461   |               \_ php process_1
vagrant   5517   |               \_ php process_2`

Comment: Aren't they called zombies?

Comment: No, the sub-processes would be gone after the master process quits. What I need is the exit codes for the sub processes.

Comment: Are you asking how `php` can get the exit status of children process (like `php -r 'system("exit 12", $ret); echo $ret;'`) or how the parent of `run-jobs` can also get the exit status of the (now orphaned) children of `run-jobs` once they exit?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It's about getting the exit status of `process_1` and `process_2` once all of them exit - the children all exit when `run-jobs` exits, there are no orphans here. I should also add that `process_1` and `process_2` are background processes created by `run-jobs`

Comment: Either they exit before `run-jobs` and they may return their status to it, or they exit after it (possibly as a result of `run-jobs` dying via a mechanism you've not described) and then they'll be orphan (if only for a very short time).

Comment: They'd have to exit to be reaped by init anyway, so there has to be something telling them to do that. Either the master kills them when dying, or they exit after noticing that a pipe (or such) to the master closes. In the first case, the master might also reap them. If there's nothing to explicity stop them, they'd go on until their job is complete, whenever that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processes report their exit status to their parent and if their parent is dead to the process of id 1 (`init`), though with recent  versions of Linux (3.4 or above), you can designate another ancestor as the *child subreaper* for that role (using `prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER)`).

Actually, after they die, processes become zombies until their parent (or `init`) retrieves their exit status (with `waitpid()` or other).

In your case, you're saying the children are dying after (as a result of?) `run-jobs` dying. That means they'll report their exit status to `init` or to the process designated as child sub-reaper.

If `init` doesn't log that (and it generally doesn't) and if you don't use auditing or process accounting, that exit status will be lost.

If on a recent version of Linux, you can create your own sub-reaper to get the pid and exit status of those orphan processes. Like with `perl`:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -le '
  require "syscall.ph";
  syscall(&SYS_prctl,36,1) >= 0 or die "cannot set subreaper: $!";

  # example running 1 child and 2 grand children:
  if (!fork) {
    # There, you would run:
    # exec("php", "run-jobs");
    if (!fork) {exec "sleep 1; exit 12"};
    if (!fork) {exec "sleep 2; exit 123"};
    exit(88)
  }
  # now reporting on all children and grand-children:
  while (($pid = wait) > 0) {
   print "$pid: " . WEXITSTATUS($?)
  }'
22425: 88
22426: 12
22427: 123
```

If you wanted to retrieve information on the dying processes (like command line, user, ppid...), you'd need to do that while they're still in the zombie state, that is before you've done a `wait()` on them.

To do that you'd need to use the `waitid()` API with the `WNOWAIT` option (and then get the information from `/proc` or the `ps` command). I don't think `perl` has an interface to that though, so you'd need to write it in another language like `C`.